# yaml pipeline fails with SOX task

Tags: azure-devops

I am using CarbonSoxCreateRecordV2 task in yaml pipeline but task fails with error complaining no release found.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your snapshot, you are using this external task: **Sox Record Creation task**, which author is **desplatsveng**.

In addition, we don't find this task from pre-defined tasks: [Build and release tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops), it should come from 3rd-party extension, and we don't find this extension from [Extensions for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops), so it maybe not a public available extension.

Therefore, we suggest that you check where you get this extension and then contact its author to investigate your issue further.